# Computing a particular expection for a family of distribution

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, probability-distributions

Consider the family of distributions having the form $$f = \frac{1}{Z({\alpha,\beta,A,B})}\prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-x+A_{j}}}\right)^{\alpha_{j}}\prod_{j=1}^{m}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{x+B_{j}}}\right)^{\beta_{j}}$$

$Z$ is the normalizing constant. Typically $n$ and $m$ are both around 3. The $\alpha_j$ and $\beta_j$ are in $\mathbb{R}^+$ and the $A_j$ and  $B_j$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

I believe a sufficient statistic for this family of distribution is the set of expectations
$$\left\{\mathbf{E}(\log(1+e^{-x+A_j}))\right\}_{j\leq n} \cup \left\{\mathbf{E}(\log(1+e^{x+B_j}))\right\}_{j \leq m}$$.

This motivates the following questions.

(1) Is there an analytic form for $\mathbf{E}(\log(1+e^{-x+A_j}))$? if so (or if not), is there an efficient way to numerically approximate it?

(2) What of $Z$?

Calculating $Z$ would be a good first step it seems, as (if I'm not mistaken) $\frac{dZ}{d \alpha_i} = -Z\mathbf{E}(\log(1+e^{-x+A_j}))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the change of variable $y = 1/(1+e^{-x})$, the integral is a special case of the Lauricella hypergeometric series

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauricella_hypergeometric_series#Integral_representation_of_FD